# CSS - border-radius: background image colors don't fit

Tags: colors, css

I have a header-menue in HTML and CSS. The left and right ending of the vertical menue should have rounded borders and a different background-image. Without the rounded-borders feature it works fine and (the right end of the menue) looks like this:

[image: right end of the menue]

The problem occurs, when i add the "border-radius:" features in css:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
```

Now the sample looks like this:

[image]

As you can see here, the colors between the allover-menue-background (comming from the left) and the right-part-background do not fit like they should (for unknown reasons only in bottom part) I have tested it with Firefox 22, Safari 6 and IE 10 - all with the same result.

Does anybody know, why this happens and how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: post your http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: that seems weird, can you put up a complete working example (jsfiddle)?

Comment: try background-size:100%

Comment: Btw, what is a 'menue'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your answers! I have made a jsfiddle and found out the reason for the problem myself:

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vFTYh/

The problem is, that i have a div-container 20px below the menu. This div has a 50px shadow.

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 50px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px#000;
box-shadow: 0 0 50px #000;
```

If i add this shadow, the menu-background and the left part of the menu-background get affected differently.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will keep this kinda solution.
Otherwise - you can also achieve round corners with img's as corners...